# python : is decorators for method arguments possible?

Tags: python, methods, arguments, decorator

Is it possible to decorate method arguments? Something like:

```
class SampleEntity (BaseEntity) :
    def someOperation (self, @Param(type="int", unit="MB")i, str) :
        pass
```

Basically I want the developer to be able to specify metadata about the class, properties, methods, arguments etc which I can process later on. For class and methods I could use decorators. So I was wondering how to do it for method arguments.

Thanks,
Litty

Comment: what kind of metadata ? can't you use the docstring for that ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, but in Python 3 you can use [annotations](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/).

```
def func(arg: Param(type = 'int', unit = 'MB')):
   pass
```

Annotations can hold any information you want, language doesn't define what should go there. You can access them with `func.__annotations__` dict later.

Comment: Thanks! Funny thing, the PEP - http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/ - says the attribute is called `func_annotations`, not `__annotations__`. Is it out of date? do PEPs *go* out of date? :).  I was getting an AttributeError and could not understand what i am doing wrong.

Comment: @letitbee: I think you should default to checking language reference first, and looking into PEPs later, at least for language features that have already been implemented. Annotations were stored in `__annotations__` even in 3.0, so I guess they've decided to change it sometime between publishing the PEP and implementing it.

Comment: Actually, and I quote PEP-1, "The PEP should provide a concise technical specification of the feature <...>". Although if you are right and we cannot trust PEPs, we cannot trust PEP-1 either! ;)

Answer (score 4):

If it's for documentation, you might be able to use the [docstring conventions](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0287/) which are commonly used.

If it's for more concrete information that you can later use in your apps, you might be able to use [enthought traits](http://github.enthought.com/traits/traits_user_manual/intro.html).

If you want static typing, you should use a different language.

Answer (score 3):

No. You can decorate functions and classes, but not parameters.

Comment: Then what will be the way to solve my problem? Will I have to decorate the method itself to give meta data about the arguments?

Comment: @Litty: Your problem is not a Python problem.  It's a Java or C++ problem.  If you switch languages, you won't have to do as much.

Answer (score 1):

You can't place the decorator in the parameter list, it has to be around the function or class.

You might want to use an [existing decorator](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Type_Enforcement_.28accepts.2BAC8-returns.29) as the starting point for your decorator.

Answer (score 1):

You can document the [function definition](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions) with annotations. What the annotations actually mean is up to you and the code using your functions.

For example:

```
def dostuff(f: str, x: "Hula hula!"):
     pass
```

Comment: Interesting. I wasn't aware of this. +1